# Plotting a result from a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

I have a question about plotting a result from a loop in Matlab. Here is the code.

```
for t=0:1:10;
  VS=3*exp(-t/3)*sin(pi*t);
  if VS>0
     VL=VS
  else VL=0

  end

end

plot(t,VL)
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('Across Voltage(V)')
title('Across Voltage Vs Time')
```

I wanna plot a figure based on the voltage from the above expression versus the time through 0 to 10. However, the figure keeps showing nothing after running the code. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are plotting outside the `for` loop. So at that time t is not a vector as you expect, its a scalar value, `t=10`. Also, `VL` depends on the execution. So you should form `t` as a vector and do the following:

```
k=0;
for t=0:1:10;
k=k+1;
  VS=3*exp(-t/3)*sin(pi*t);
  if VS>0
    VL(k,1)=VS
  else VL(k,1)=0
  end
end
plot(0:10,VL)
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('Across Voltage(V)')
title('Across Voltage Vs Time')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this still does not work. It will pop up 10 figure windows and each of them contains nothing of curve.

Comment: still popped up ten windows with nothing inside. I want those ten values in one figure window with curve. I think the ten windows popping up is because the "plot statement" is in the loop which means "plot" ten times.

Comment: I am very sorry for the stupid code... corrected it... wasted your and my time...

Comment: lol, that still does not work. I have tried this way as well. it will say "Inner matrix dimensions must agree." pointing at the "VS "expression.

Comment: I know... you should try the edited code... that works... but I don't know if thats what you want. Please tell me if you don't understand the difference between `*` and `.*` in MATLAB. Because that is the edit I made.

Comment: that looks great. Thanks a lot. But I am wondering why we use .* between the two function "exp" and "sin", do they not agree with same dimension?

Comment: both are `1x11`, so according to matrix rules, two `1x11` matrix cannot be multiplied. `.*` does element wise multiplication, that is, 1st element with 1st, 2nd with 2nd and so on... Please accept the answer if this is what you want.

Comment: is there a way that we can put the code in a loop or at least using 'if' &'end' statement?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: your code works but I think my instructor want to see our code in a loop or using `if & end` because we are learning these two statements. Actually, I am also wondering if there are three possible situations, say if VS>1, VL=VS; if VS=1 VL=2; if VS<1; VL=3, how can we fix that.

Comment: try storing `VL` in an array on every iteration... if you don't get it... I will tell you.

Comment: is it like `if VS>0 VL[]=VS` `else VL[]=0` ?

Comment: `if VS>0 VL(t+1,1)=VS`. I have edited the code. You almost got there. But the plot is different. You should investigate why...

Comment: `for t=0:0.01:10;
VS=3*exp(-t/3).*sin(t*pi);

    if VS>0
        VL(t+1,1)=VS
    else 
        VL(t+1,1)=0
  
    end
end

plot(t,VL);
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('Across Voltage(V)')
title('Across Voltage Vs Time')` it shows "Attempted to access VL(1.01,1); index must be a positive integer or logical."

Comment: edited the code. You need to introduce an index, you cannot have `t` as an index when it takes a non-integer value.

Comment: VL(k,1), what does the "1" after the comma?

Comment: oh, that will make `VL` a column vector. Otherwise `VL` will be a row vector.